# Line break in Prettyprint string in HTML

Tags: html, css

How to use break lines in a string defined under class="prettyprint". I tried using \n, \n, 
 but no luck.

```
<pre class="prettyprint">
...
...
 <span class="str">
 "text1 \n text2 \n text3"
 </span>
```

Answer (score 2):

In PRE enters are interpreted like a newlines. `\n` are normal 2 chars inside PRE, with no special effect.

```html
<pre class="prettyprint">
...
...
 <span class="str">
 "text1
 text2
 text3"
 </span>
```